# Call multiple JsonHttpResponseHandler but only one onFinish

Tags: java, android, asynchttpclient, loopj

I created a layout in my app where I have multiple checkboxes and once the user checked some and clicks ok, I search it via a `jsonHttpResponse` (each iteration is an item that was checked):

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    String itemID = items.get( i ).getitemID();

    MyitemClient client = new MyitemClient();
    client.getitems( itemID, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                final Myitem items = Myitem.fromJson( response );
                itemNames = itemNames + items.getTitle() + "\n";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            String TimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat( TimeFormat );
            String dateText = df2.format( dateInMillis );

            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference usernamedb = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "UserData" );
            usernamedb.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String NewMessage = document.getString( "username" ) + " wants these items: \n\n" + itemNames + "\nUntil " + dateText + "\n\nDo you confirm?";
                        chatOrganizer.addMessageToChat( chatID, auth.getUid(), receiverID, NewMessage, true );

                    }
                }

            } );
        }
    } );

}
```

and the client is:

```
public class MyitemClient {

    private static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://www.somesiteinhere..../";
    private AsyncHttpClient client;

    public MyitemClient() {
        this.client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    }

    public void getitems(final String query, JsonHttpResponseHandler handler) {
        try {
            client.get(API_BASE_URL + URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8"), handler);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {

        }
    }

}
```

My goal is to get from that client the itemTitle and once all of the titles were obtained, to launch a message as shown in `chatOrganizer`.

My problem is that in this implementation it enters to `onFinish` as many times as the iteration and therefore it prints this message for every item.

How can I make sure that it will enter onFinish only once all of the iterations are finished?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one solution can be that:

- You write two handlers, one with dummy onFinish (the method does nothing) and one with your current implementation onFinish.
- Check the index of i. If i is not the last item, pass the dummy handler to client.getitems as the second parameter. If i is the last item, pass the other to client.getItems(...).

i hope that this idea is helpful =)

```
if (i != items.size() -1) {
  client.getItems (itemID, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                final Myitem items = Myitem.fromJson( response );
                itemNames = itemNames + items.getTitle() + "\n";
                //TODO save item names
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            //DO nothing
        }
  })
} else {
  client.getItems (itemID, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                final Myitem items = Myitem.fromJson( response );
                itemNames = itemNames + items.getTitle() + "\n";
                //TODO save item names
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            String TimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat( TimeFormat );
            String dateText = df2.format( dateInMillis );

            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference usernamedb = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "UserData" );
            ...
        }
  })
}
```

Comment: I will be honest, I tried using the index of i to find if its last or not but im getting errors since it has to be final or static because it is in inner class

Comment: is the problem now about checking if i is last or not? if that, the last index is items.size() -1. then you just need to check if (i == items.size() -1)

Comment: can you write example of what you mean please?